# Don't Allow External Users To Authenticate That Aren't In Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

For example, in my development environment, I will have an admin create a user. I don't want anyone but the admin to be able to create users. This will allow me to have a true development environment by controlling which users have access to the database.

I basically want to configure security rules so that users other than the admin user are not able to create users. I don't want anonymous users to be able to access my dev site and create users. This feels like the only way to ensure that people outside of my organization are not allowed to access the development environment.

Is there a way to deny users ability to sign-up in your firebase?

Comment: There is no way to prevent user from authenticating. But authentication itself does not grant them access to resources. You can use security rules to ensure only authorized users have access to the data.

Comment: ok, and I suppose for non-technical external users I could create a page after sign-in that tells them they don't have access to the data.